# Were the Londo premonition death scene reshot in season 3?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, babylon-5

In season 1 we see the recurring scene of what would become Londo and G’Kar killing each other for the first time. In this scene G’Kar has just 1 eye and Londo is emperor.

Later on in season 3 we see the scene again in a different form as Sheridan and Delenn travel through time. I haven't got to it yet but it may be that we see this scene play out again in seasons 4 or 5.

was this scene reshot for later seasons or was it all filmed during season 1 filming and then different parts used in later seasons? I have tried watching the scenes and can't see any continuity errors (outfits, etc) but that doesn't prove it was all shot in season 1.

Comment: Although your questions are strongly related, I'd separate them into different posts.

Comment: Ok wasn’t sure if I should or not :) if there is a general consensus happy to in the morning :)

Comment: have split out to 2 questions

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it was restaged and reshot.**

Although the actions and makeup appear the same, the lighting is completely different between the scenes.

Londo's emperor premonition from *Coming of Shadows* is washed in a red backlight, either to link it all to "hand reaching from the stars", or to emphasize the presence of the enemy, G'kar.
[image: Londo on throne, Coming of Shadows]
[image: G'kar strangles Londo, Coming of Shadows]

The flash-forward from *War Without End* however, is backlit in white, and is also from a different camera angle.

[image]